# Calling method from different class sometimes works and sometimes doesn't

Tags: ios, xcode, class, methods, call

I am trying call set of methods from one class that reside in another class.

The methods all reside in my `ViewController.m` class and I am trying to call them from my other class called `MyClass.m`.

Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

The errors I get are

`unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1071c0050`

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[ViewController setProgressValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1071c0050'`

When error suggests that something went wrong at `[ViewController setProgressValue:]` which is exclusively called from within `ViewController.m` which also resides there.

The flow looks like this:
`ViewController.methodA -> MyClass.methodB -> ViewController.methodB`

This does not work, but the following works
`ViewController.methodA -> MyClass.methodB -> ViewController.methodC`

How come that the first flow doesn't works but the second does?

Answer (score 1):

The error is *very* descriptive. You are calling a method that does not exist.

You're calling `setProgressValue:` as a class method, it probably is an instance method. Please note the '+' in the error description. You need to call it on a concrete instance of `ViewController`.

Comment: How do I do that? Could you give me a reference document or some reference code on how to call it on a concrete instance of `ViewController`.

Comment: If you don't know those differences, I'd really start with some basic introduction to programming in Objective-C. If you post the code, we might fix it at least.

Answer (score 0):

If I was to make an educated guess without seeing your code I would say that in your *header* you have a method declared that looks something like this:

`+ (void)setProgressValue:(float)progress`

And that in your *implementation* you have a method that looks like this:

`- (void)setProgressValue:(float)progress {
    // Blah...
}`

Notice that the method declarations are different. One is declared as static (notice the `+`) and the other declared as an instance method (notice the `-` in the implementation one). Your header is declaring that it exists when in fact that static method doesn't exist in your implementation.

Comment: If that is what you have then that is the problem. You need to change your declaration in your header from 

`+ (void)setProgressValue:(float)progress`

to

`- (void)setProgressValue:(float)progress`

Notice the `-` instead of the `+`.